# What Qualifies as "Business Deduction for Work-Related Education" Under US Tax Code Publication 970

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, irs, education

I work as a Software Developer.  Using Topic [513](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc513.html) Publication [970](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p970/index.html) Chapter [12](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p970/ch12.html)  of the US Tax Code would I be able to deduct any of the following?

- Paying for and taking PTO to attend a conference and workshops for programming like [Clojure/West](http://clojurewest.org/)
- Paying for and taking a programming/analysis specialization on Coursera like [Data Science](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/jhu-data-science)

Also would I need to fill out both form [2106-EZ](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f2106ez.pdf) and [2106](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f2106.pdf) or just one of them?

Comment: A course that is directly required to retain your job and not reimbursed by your employer qualifies. Generally nothing else does. You might want to adk your employer if they offer any kind of tuition assistance plan and whether these courses would be covered by that.

Comment: I see, so it has to be directly required, meaning I have to take it instead of wanting to take it?

Comment: That's not quite true @keshlam as I read Pub 970, which lists two tests and you can meet either one. It's possible the OP's expenses would meet the second test. Note however that, if you otherwise qualify for the deduction, you can only deduct these expenses above the [2% AGI limit](https://www.taxslayer.com/support/knowledgebasearticle245.aspx), so the actual savings may be fairly minimal depending on the costs and your income.

Comment: Also note: "You can't deduct personal or capital expenses. For example, you can't deduct the dollar value of vacation time or annual leave you take to attend classes. This amount is a personal expense."

Comment: @ZachLipton thanks that is how I read it. I'll consult a tax accountant before I make any plans.